# Defining optional record type in Avro schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I am having difficulties in defining the avro schema for the following xml where SubElement1 is optional:

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Element1 attribute1="attr_value1" attribute2="attr_value2">
    <SubElement1 attribute1="attr_value">
</Element1>
```

**AVRO Schema**

```
{
  "namespace": "com.kafka.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Element1",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "attribute1", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "attribute2", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "SubElement1",
             "type":["null", {
                 "type": "record",
                 "name": "SubElement1",
                 "fields":[
                  {"name" : "attribute1", "type" : "string" , "default":""}
                 ]
             }], "default":null
        }
  ]
}
```

This works fine when SubElement1 is not present:

```
"SubElement1": null
```

When there is SubElement1 present, this results into the following where the namespace is added:

```
"SubElement1": {
    "com.kafka.avro.SubElement1": {
      "attribute1": "attr_value1"
    }
  }
```

I Would like to completely omit the namespace part as below:

```
"SubElement1": {
          "attribute1": "attr_value1"
      }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your output is the JSON encoding. Unfortunately, the specification states that the encoding should look like that: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding

There is an outstanding issue on the Avro issue tracker about this feature request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1582. In that issue, I think someone provided some code that would do what you want, but as of right now there is no way to do this with the standard library.